# внутренний счетчик массива

Tags: php

Существует ли какой-то способ сбросить внутренний счетчик массива? (ну или как оно называется, не знаю)

Пример:

```
$a = [
    2 => 2,
    3 => 3,
];
unset($a[3]);
$a[] = 4;
var_dump($a);
```

результатом будет:

```
array(1) {
  [2] => int(2),
  [4] => int(4)
}
```

Что, не то чтобы мешает, но да, а еще дико бесит.

Есть ли какой-то способ, **не пересоздавая массив**, сбросить в нём эту самую штуку, чтобы после

```
kakaya_to_mahinaciya($a)
$a[] = 4;
```

получить:

```
array(1) {
  [2] => int(2),
  [3] => int(4)
}
```

Comment: А 2 вас не бесит ? :)) Можно сбросить до нуля - array_values()

Comment: @splash58, "не пересоздавая массив". Вообще, я тут баловался с ArrayObject, и внезапно осознал, что с ним нифига не работает. Попробовал сделать аналог array_merge своими руками - и вот столкнулся с таким явлением, что, судя по всему, никак нельзя сбросить этот внутренний счетчик, если не пересоздать объект/массив. При этом, ясное дело, сам ArrayObject не особо привлекателен в чистом виде, привлекает наследование от него. Может там в 7 php как-то решили уже какую-то из этих проблем?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вы в своем вопросе фактически привели пример из [документации по массивам](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php), иллюстрирующем как они работают в принципе.

> Как уже говорилось выше, если ключ не был указан, то будет взят максимальный из существующих целочисленных (integer) индексов, и новым ключом будет это максимальное значение (в крайнем случае 0) плюс 1. Если целочисленных индексов еще нет, то ключом будет 0 (ноль).
>
> Учтите, что максимальное целое значение ключа не обязательно существует в массиве в данный момент. Оно могло просто существовать в массиве какое-то время, с тех пор как он был переиндексирован в последний раз. Следующий пример это иллюстрирует:

*и тут можно привести ваш пример кода.*

там же явным текстом написано, что для переиндексации использовать `array_values`.
Так что в целом ответ на ваш вопрос - "*никак, так устроен пхп*".

Единственное замечание, что `array_values` сбросит ассоциативные ключи, поэтому в случае смешанных массивов можно использовать `array_merge` с единственным аргументом - самим массивом. Это оставит строковые ключи и перенумерует целочисленные.

> В результирующем массиве значения исходного массива с числовыми ключами будут перенумерованы в возрастающем порядке, начиная с нуля.

Comment: Ну как так... я подозревал, что нет способа, но я надеялся... это вот ваще нечестно.